# PHP: $_GET not working/ nothing being displayed on page

Tags: php, post, get

I have been working on a simple website for a while, trying to learn PHP. I have made a simple php form, using bootstrap.

I use the GET method to get the text from the input into the url, and it shows up on the search.php url shown here:
[URL](https://i.gyazo.com/3592e464c8311dad909f6ec75e824e1a.png)

File Structure:
[Screenshot of directories](https://i.gyazo.com/c979be5390997bc6b51a090b43b21cad.png)

For some reason, when i try to echo the value on the search.php page, the web page is blank. I have probably made a stupid error, so any help would be great!

**index.php code:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Mc Report</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Mc Report">
  <meta name="author" content="Cre8tionz">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.css">
  <script>
  $(function(){

      $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){

        $(".but:first-child").text($(this).text());
        $(".but:first-child").val($(this).text());

     });

  });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container container-table">
    <div class="row vertical-center-row">
      <div class="text-center col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
        <div class="main-logo">
          <img src="img/logo.png"></img>
        </div>
          <div class="row">
            **<form action="search.php" method="get" novalidate="novalidate">
              <div class="col-lg-10">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <input name="q" type="search" class="form-control" aria-label="..." placeholder="Search for a username">
                  <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="button" class="but btn btn-default dropdown-toggle pull-right" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Catageory<span class="caret"></span></button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                      <li><a href="#">Mc-Market Username</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Minecraft Username</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Minecraft UUID</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-2">
                <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>**
          </div>
      </div>
      <footer>
        <div class="footer">
           <div class="container narrow row-fluid text-center navbar-fixed-bottom">
              <div class="col-lg-4">
                Mc Report
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-4">
                About
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-4">
                Copyright &copy; 2016
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**search.php code:**

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
  if( $_GET["q"] ) {
    print_r($_GET);
    $searchquery =  $_GET["q"];
    echo $searchquery;
  }
?>
</html>
</body>
```

Comment: above your code working in my environment in *search.php * file to remove the html codes except *php* code . also remove ~phpinfo()~

Comment: I think that you are opened that page from file, not from server (lampp, xampp, wamp...). Php pages must be processed by server first

Comment: @Aleksandar I have it on a Xampp server, but its still not working : https://i.gyazo.com/96ff60591c7dfbb3c6fc231e1360cad3.png

Comment: *web page is blank* means something went wrong. Add these lines `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the very top of your PHP script and see if it yields any error or not.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul Here is the console: https://i.gyazo.com/9319c6ae2526925171c3a2f4d7f5dfe4.png The page is still blank

Answer (score 0):

Your URL is file:///...
Most likely you are opening your local files in a browser. The browser cannot execute PHP scripts, so it considers the whole PHP code between < and > as a long unknown tag. Tags are not displayed, so you see a blank page.

You need a webserver to execute PHP scripts.
The most simple way to run a webserver is to run `php -S localhost:8001` in your project root (mcreport.net directory).
Then open `http://localhost:8001/` in your browser.

Comment: I forgot to screenshot the Xampp file path. I am actually running it in a webserver, I was just silly and forgot to show it. Here is the path: https://i.gyazo.com/96ff60591c7dfbb3c6fc231e1360cad3.png

Comment: Open the source code of the page in the browser. Is it empty?

Comment: Check the server status code for the search.php request. You can check it in Inspector (Developer Tools), on network tab. Most likely it is 200 or 500. 
Check xampp error log for PHP errors.